# Bot Service is not working with Node.js . Error cannot find module 'botbuilder'

Tags: node.js, azure-bot-service

I created a Bot Service through 'Azure Portal' with Node.js and LUIS. When the Bot is created, i can see the 'Chat interface' loading forever with a message 'Loading chat interface'.
[Bot developer interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlUKR.png)

So I opened Bot through 'My bots' in 'dev.botframework.com' and tested the connection. It failed with the below error.
[Bot chat window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIqsy.png)

When i pinged 'Hi' in the chat box there, i could see the error in the logs 'Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: Error: Cannot find module 'botbuilder'

I could see 'botbuildr' dependency in 'package.json' as below.

```
{
  "name": "luisbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "^3.7.0",
    "botbuilder-azure": "3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "restify": "^4.3.0"
  },  
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Any suggestions for the error?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I had an existing QnA knowledge base and tried to create the bot service on top of that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this same problem and solved it by running `npm install` in kudu console.

Go to your Bot Service's **Settings**-tab and click to open "**Advanced settings**". There you can find "**Advanced Tools**" (kudu) under Development tools. Open **Debug Console** and **`cd`** to the folder where you have `package.json` (for me it was D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages) and run **`npm install`**.

After that you can communicate with the bot in **dev.botframework.com** although the chat interface won't still work in Azure portal.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :) Please mark the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I applied npm install, after an error was risen about dependencies (botbuilder-azure)
I added the dependency to package json and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Install botbuilder by below cmd:

> npm install --save botbuilder